# NSObject to json?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I want to convert `personArray` to a JSON string, and send a request to the server.

I tried something like the following code:

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    int registered;
}
+ (NSMutableArray *) select;
```

```
NSMutableArray *personArray = [Person select]; 


NSString *json = @"{ \"";//TODO

for (int i =0 ;i < [personArray count]; i++) {
    Person *temp = [Person objectAtIndex:i];

    [json stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"name\": \"%@\"", temp.name]
}
json = [json stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"} \""]];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:[global userID] forKey:@"user_id"];
[request setPostValue:json forKey:@"json_key"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-type" value:@"application/json"]; 

[request startSynchronous];
```

The server receives the following data:

```
{ \"\"name\": \"Tom\"}
```

The server code is this:

```
$json = $_POST['json_key'];
echo $json;
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json; // prints nothing
```

Is there any way to remove the slash, or a prettier solution for converting the object to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that the JSON representation is being generated properly, use a general purpose JSON generator (such as Stig Brautaset's [JSON Framewark](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) or [yajl-objc](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc)) rather than ad hoc conversion.

JSON Framework:

```
@interface Person(SBJson)
-(id)proxyForJson;
@end

@implementation Person(SBJson)
-(id)proxyForJson {
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    name,@"name",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:registered],@"registered",
     nil];
}
@end

...
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:[[Person select] JSONRepresentation] forKey:@"json_key"];
```

yajl-objc:

```
@interface Person(YAJL)
-(id)JSON;
@end

@implementation Person(YAJL)
-(id)JSON {
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    name,@"name",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:registered],@"registered",
     nil];
}
@end

...
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:[[Person select] yajl_JSONString] forKey:@"json_key"];
```

See also:

- [Encoding custom classes using yajl-objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628689/)
- [How to generate JSON programatically using JSON framework for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039780/)
- [Send NSMutableArray as JSON using JSON-Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245191/)

Answer (score 1):

On the server, you probably have [magic_quotes_gpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) turned on.  Try something more like this:

```
$json = $_POST['json_key'];

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $json = stripslashes($json);
}

echo $json;
$json = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *json = @"{ \"";//TODO
```

and

```
json = [json stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"} \""]];
```

Look mighty suspicious to me. You're sticking a quote at the start of your json string, which will lead to the the first key having a stray " in front of it. The " at the end just looks bogus.

Why not use an actual JSON library (e.g. [touchjson](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) or [sbjson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)) rather than cobbling together bits of strings ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this gives you anything at all. For starters, this line…

```
[json stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"name\": \"%@\"", temp.name]];
```

… does nothing at all. `stringByAppendingFormat:` returns a new string based on the receiver (i.e. `json`), it does not modify the receiver. Also, you're creating a new string with a format, to append to `json` with a format; it could be simplified to:

```
json = [json stringByAppendingFormat:@"\"name\": \"%@\"", temp.name];
```

Also, rather than continuously creating new strings and potentially flooding the autorelease pool, use an `NSMutableString` instead, and use the `appendFormat:` or `appendString:` method which **do** modify the receiver rather than creating new strings.

As others have mentioned, the reason why the JSON might not be decoded properly is because it may not be well-formed, there is a stray `\"` in your JSON string.